# How to have shadows on a solid gauge with highcharts

Tags: highcharts

We are using multi kpi gauge highchart(solid gauge) and here we are facing an issue with border shadows of the backgrounds. Due to lack of the shadow effect the background is looking like very transparent.

[image]

We need some effect like this but we are not able to achieve this effect.

[image]

The background is very light due to which it is looking like there is no track of it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, unlike other series such as Pie Solid Gauge, it does not have a shadow property with which you can define shadows.

However you can achieve this using the render function in which you generate 2 circles via SVGRenderer:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    ...
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const chart = this,
          center = chart.pane[0].center,
          x = chart.plotLeft + center[0],
          y = chart.plotTop + center[1],
          r = chart.pane[0].axis.axisGroup.element.getBBox().width / 2 - 1,
          smallestRadius = chart.series.reduce((minRadius, currentSeries) => {
            const currentRadius = parseInt(currentSeries.data[0].radius);
            return currentRadius < minRadius ? currentRadius : minRadius;
          }, Infinity),
          smallR = r - (smallestRadius / 100) * r;
          
        if(!chart.paneBackground) {
            chart.paneBackground = chart.renderer.circle().attr({
            fill: '#fff',
          }).add().shadow({
            color: 'black',
            width: 10
          });
        }
        chart.paneBackground.attr({
            x: x, y: y, r: r
        })

        if(!chart.paneInnerBackground) {
            chart.paneInnerBackground = chart.renderer.circle().attr({
          fill: '#fff',
          zIndex: 6,
        }).add().shadow({
          color: 'black',
          width: 10
        });
        }
        chart.paneInnerBackground.attr({
            x: x, y: y, r: smallR
        })
      }
    }
  }
  ...
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/16tfarc9/
API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#circle